# How to make water transparent on openstreemap-carto style?

Tags: openstreetmap, style, mapnik, color, bathymetry

I have build up manually a tile server on Ubuntu 14.04. LTS, by following switch2osm's guide and have used the openstreetmap-carto style.

Now I intend to add a base layer, underneath the current one, that will display the contour depth lines.

That's why I want to make the water transparent.

How can this be implemented?

I have seen in the scripts/ directory the generate_roads_colours.py. Should I create a new script for water in a similar manner, or one exists?

Comment: As per the [Tour], which I note that you have not yet taken, there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: I made some edits, hope now the question is better expressed